# How to scale a room along the z axis so one wall stays in place and only the far wall moves?

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, scale, steam-vr

I'm a Psychology undergrad working in a spatial navigation lab where we design Unity environments and have people navigate them in VR. There's a lot of stuff we do here that doesn't involve coding, but I was assigned to one of the projects that involves coding. We use a package with a bunch of scripts for data collection, but nobody in the lab actually wrote any of those scripts and we (mostly) have zero idea what we're doing when we script things. We usually find a way to adapt something somebody else wrote, but we can't exactly do that when we need to write something new. This is a problem since some of our VR experiments require basic functions like moving multiple objects at the press of a button or quickly changing to a different environment fast enough to avoid breaking participant immersion and there's no code from previous experiments that we can "borrow".

For the experiment I'm helping with, I just need to be able to shift two game objects along the z-axis and scale a third along the z-axis according to a variable defined by a separate gaussian-distribution script we use for random number generation. The participant starts in a simple room that consists of 4 walls and a carpet. They navigate to one wall, then this script kicks in while they are facing the wall and extends the other end of the room by a random value while the participant is still in the environment facing the back wall. To do this, I intend to scale the carpet beneath the participant by the random Gaussian value from the script I mentioned earlier and then shift the wall and door behind the participant by a mathematically-determined value that will shift them to the same point that the carpet's end moved to when it was scaled. I'm capable of figuring out the conversion, but I still need to write the actual script and I have zero clue what I'm doing. I'm sure a 3rd-week freshman Coding 101 student could do this, so would anyone here be willing to tell me what I'd need to do?

Here's some pseudo-code I wrote that should better illustrate what I want to do:

```
> get {gaussian value}
> set object [carpet] scale to (10.5 x ({GaussianValue} x 2))
var {posadd} = (however far the Gaussian value moves the end of the carpet when we scale it)
> set object [Door] position to (-8.233004, 0.3, 10.29001+{posadd})
> set object [Door-Side Wall] position to (0, 3.36, -5.65+{posadd})
> say "hello, world!"
```

reset pseudo-code script (for resetting the environment between trials)

```
>set object [carpet] scale to (z=10.5)
>set object [Door] position to (-8.233004, 0.3, 10.29001)
>set object [Door-Side Wall] position to (0, 3.36, -5.65)
>say "hello, world!"
```

default object values:
carpet:
scale > z=10.5
door:
z-coordinate > z=10.29001
door-side wall:
z-coordinate > z=-5.65

I'm not sure if the grad student running the study wants all this to happen at the push of a button or the moment the participant reaches a certain coordinate. I think I'll just worry about that later. We're using an older version of Unity since the newer versions seem to break some of the stuff we do with our experiments. It should be version 2019.4.29f1. We're working with Steam-VR, if that's relevant.

Comment: It sounds to me like one or more people in your lab would be well advised to work through a few beginner scripting tutorials for Unity. There are tons available and they'll cover core concepts like moving and scaling objects, so your team can be more autonomous in creating any script you need.

Comment: I will second this. Judging by the pseudocode you seem to already have the mindset that will make it relatively easy to learn basic Unity C# scripting in a matter of days. Btw writing the code will be the easier part compared to creating a way for it to be triggered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out some scripting tutorials. I'm glad to see that I've already got the mindset down!